# How many different binary matrices are there of size n x m, where rows can be interchanged and still remain the same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, linear-independence

I think it's the same as finding the number of equivalent matrices by elementary Gaussian transformations, since it's binary.

Maybe the question could be rephrased to the number of linearly independent vectors in a binary matrix and therefore they would be the total of different matrices echeloned.

I don't get the combinatorics

Example

For 2 x 2 matrices. I have 16 different binary matrices, but the matrix {01,10} is equal to {10,01} if I change the rows and I would only have 10 different matrices.

I would like to know if it is possible to find a formula for matrices of n x m

Comment: What to you mean by "remain the same matrix"? Also, what do you mean by "rows can be interchanged"? Can any pair of rows be interchanged, or just one?

Comment: I don't understand your title: it says you are interested in matrices whose rows $R_1,\dots,R_n$ satisfy $\forall k\quad R_k=R_1.$ This is certainly not what you mean. So what?

Comment: If two rows of the matrix are different, then if you interchange them, the matrix will change. So at the moment, it seems as if you demand *all* rows of the matrix to be equal.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you mean the following. Consider the action of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ on the space of $n \times m$ binary matrices obtained by permuting the rows. How many orbits are there? In fact, when $n = m = 2$ there are indeed 10 orbits.

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^m$ possible choices for a row, and what we are interested in (if I understand the question correctly) is the number of [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) of size $n$ composed of those rows.  The number of such multisets is

$$\binom{2^m+n-1}{n}$$
by a well-known formula.